# Is there any guide or tool available to convert JMeter .jmx file to Karate DSL feature files?

Tags: jmeter, karate

Is there any tool or guide available to convert JMeter .jmx files to karate DSL .feature files?

We have a large size .jmx files which I would like to convert to karate dsl format and use karate standalone jar to execute the tests from command line.

Comment: You may need also a tool to convert back if you return to JMeter ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no such tool.

Comment: Ok. No tool but is there any guideline or suggestion available anywhere? I am more interested in extracting data from response body and using it. Also, how cookies and headers are managed. JMeter does all this very easily.

Comment: @rahoolm for cookies and headers please read the docs and all your questions will be answered. and then ask SPECIFIC questions if needed. Karate does it MORE easily :P - one hint is in Karate you can paste JSON into tests and it will just work most of the time, so it should not take you much time. but based on the questions you are asking, I am not sure :)

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks I was able to do what I wanted to using karate DSL, it was very easy to change my jmx file to karate feature file with very less efforts. Great tool!!!

Comment: Hi @rahoolm is it possible to share the solution here. I am also looking to integrate the jmx file in karate script. It would be helpful for us.

Comment: @oliver no solution as such, I just did it manually. Since my script was easy enough. I read karate documentation properly again.